# Filtering the response fileds in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using EF for building WEB API. I want to filter the columns of the table while displaying response. As there are many fields in table which are unnecessary too, it gets problem serializing the contents.

SQL Design of Table from where API is to be built:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[flight_new](
    [flight_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [utc_departure_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [airline_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [flight_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [flight_status_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [aircraft_type_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [matriculation_rcd] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [operating_airline_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [operating_flight_number] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [origin_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [destination_rcd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [leg_inventory_flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [flight_comment] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [internal_comment] [nvarchar](450) NULL,
    [controlling_agency_code] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [open_book_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [open_book_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [cancelled_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [cancelled_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [locked_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [locked_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [create_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [create_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [update_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [update_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [schedule_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [free_seating_flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [auto_open_checkin_flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [allow_web_checkin_flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [flight_information_1] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [flight_information_2] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [flight_information_3] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [activated_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [activated_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [inactivated_by] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [inactivated_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [exclude_statistics_flag] [tinyint] NULL,
    [dot_reporting_date_time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I have created a new class for displaying the required field as, But I want to display the response only as:

```
  private class ExpectedResponse
        {
            public DateTime? utc_departure_date { get; set; }
            public string flight_number { get; set; }
            public string origin_rcd { get; set; }
            public string destination_rcd { get; set; }
            public string flight_status_rcd { get; set; }
        }
```

The controller methods for getting response is as below.

```
    // GET api/FlightInfo
//Default Method
    public IQueryable<ExpectedResponse> Getflight_new()
    {
        return db.flight_new
         .ToList()
         .Select(p => new ExpectedResponse
         {
             utc_departure_date = p.utc_departure_date,
             flight_number = p.flight_number,
             origin_rcd = p.origin_rcd,
             destination_rcd = p.destination_rcd,
             flight_status_rcd = p.flight_status_rcd,
         })
         .AsQueryable();
    }

    private class ExpectedResponse
    {
        public DateTime? utc_departure_date { get; set; }
        public string flight_number { get; set; }
        public string origin_rcd { get; set; }
        public string destination_rcd { get; set; }
        public string flight_status_rcd { get; set; }
    }
```

I get the error while building as : `'System.Linq.IQueryable<YCFAPI.Controllers.FlightInfoController.ExpectedResponse>' is less accessible than method 'YCFAPI.Controllers.FlightInfoController.Getflight_new()'`

How do i get the desired response. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `private` to `public` here

```
public class ExpectedResponse
{
  public DateTime? utc_departure_date { get; set; }
  public string flight_number { get; set; }
  public string origin_rcd { get; set; }
  public string destination_rcd { get; set; }
  public string flight_status_rcd { get; set; }
}
```

And I would move ExpectedResponse to another file for example in the Models folder as `ExpectedResponse.cs`. Just to provide a clean **[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)** structure, so that the Controller does all the logic and the Models hold the data, get the data or define how the properties of the specific data look